# How should I name modules? They often conflict with local variables

Tags: python-2.7, naming-conventions, pep

I'm starting my first large python project, and I'm running into a common issue. I'll have some file `response.py` that is purely functional and has no classes. I often end up doing this:

```
from my_cookbook.util import response

...

def foo():
    response = bar.get_response()
    response.baz(response)
```

The reponse *module* operates on the response *variable*, which of course conflicts. PEP8 says [package and module names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) should be lowercase, as should [local variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).

**Question**: Is there a way I can mitigate the amount of naming conflicts I get without sacrificing readability of both module and variable names?

Comment: Pick your names carefully? This is really not that big a problem.

Comment: Usually you'd just suffix the local version with an underscore: `response_`. Alternatively, suffix the module on import: `from ... import response as response_`.

Comment: any evidence that those are common practices? I'm hoping to bring new people on to this project and I want to stick to as many standards as possible